# Rendering HTML rich text in Silvlerlight without using windowless mode

Tags: html, silverlight

I'm trying to find a control for our project that will allow us to render HTML content in Silverlight, without having to use windowless mode or be an out-of-browser app. All of the controls I've found so far require windowless mode. For technical reasons, windowless mdoe and out of browser apps are not possible for us.

The intention is to use the control to show formatted text in our Help system, so if there's a control out there that does a partial implementation, it might still be useful to us. We are mostly looking for the ability for the help content to be defined in some kind of rich text format (most likely HTML) such that it can have formatting, bullets, perhaps tables, images, etc.

Can anyone suggest a control that can do this? We're currently using Silverlight 3, but Silverlight 4 is in the pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the Vectorlight controls for this sort of thing for both displaying and editing HTML based content.  The one I've used is [Rich Text Editor](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/controls/rich_text_editor.aspx) which is the original control that works in SL3 and 4.  A new one has been introduced called the [Html RichTextArea](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/controls/html_richtextarea.aspx).  Note both are actually HTML based. I don't know how well the newer one works, I suspect it is based on the SL4 rich text stuff however the original control works fine.

Comment: Just a warning with the Html Rich TextArea from VectorLight. I got the latest version and it was throwing exceptions left and right with HTML that I was loading into it.
I checked the source and it looks like their styling parsing for "font-size" doesn't account for the "pt" which is standard in CSS. So you'll need to alter the source to remove the "pt" before it attempts to parse the font-size.

Comment: @MVelasquez: This has been a problem for a long time, it only understands px not pt.  Fortunately px in Silveright is always 96DPI hence in order to handle pt correctly you need to replace pt sizes with px sizes (multiply by 1.3333) when displaying HTML.  When retrieving HTML you can replace px with pt by multiplying by 0.75.