# Can I render HTML in Silverlight?

Tags: html, silverlight, text-formatting

Is there any way to display formatted text in Silverlight?

I have a database of articles with HTML formatting (p,b,i,h1,h2 tags). I need to figure out a way to display them in a Silverlight application while retaining the formatting from the database.

Comment: It does not necessary need to be html. It can be converted to something else easily. I just need to save and display formatted text.

Comment: See:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4735350/rendering-html-rich-text-in-silvlerlight-without-using-windowless-mode

Answer (score 4):

There is an [HtmlTextBlock control](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2007/09/10/bringing-a-bit-of-html-to-silverlight-htmltextblock-makes-rich-text-display-easy.aspx) written by David Anson (from MS) which has support for the following HTML elements:

- A
- B
- BR
- EM
- I
- P
- STRONG
- U

Fortunately, the source is distributed, and you'd have to provide support for `H*` tags.

However, if you are using Silverlight 4, then you can use the [WebBrowser class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.95).aspx) and just load your HTML into that.  Just note (as [santiagoIT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251680/santiagoit) does in the comments) that the WebBrowser control will only work if you are running out-of-browser.

Comment: Beware though, WebBrowser only works if your app is running 'Out Of Browser'!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you don't have a standard oob control to do that. But I know some guys that develop theirs own control, like this one: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2007/09/10/bringing-a-bit-of-html-to-silverlight-htmltextblock-makes-rich-text-display-easy.aspx It's simple but can solve your question. ;)